# how to get the maximum Primary key id result on the basis of each foreign key id in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

Could please anyone tell me how I can return all the rows which has a maximum primary key id against each and every foreign key id.

e.g. If I have an Applicant and Notes Table. Applicant table has ApplicantId as Primary key and Notes Table has NotesId as Primary key. ApplicantId is the Foreign key in Notes Table with One to Many relationship.

Here i want to get the maximum NotesId result against each unique ApplicantId from Notes table . Anyone's help will really be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. Could please anyone tell me how I can get other columns data from Notes table along with the ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ApplicantId, MAX(NotesId)
FROM Notes
GROUP BY ApplicantId;
```

To get the rest of the record you can do:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM notes n
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT max(notesId) AS maxid
  FROM notes
  GROUP BY applicantId
  ) n2 ON n.NotesId = n2.maxid
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f791c/2)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much Filipe for your quick response. I also want to get other columns data from the Notes table for those Id's. Could you please tell me how I can do that

Comment: @waseem. I added a query to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT applicantId, max(notesId) 
from Notes
group by applicantId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a group by or an over clause, like this

```
select 
  applicantid,
  max(notesid) over (partition by applicantid)
from table
```

or this

```
select 
  applicantid,
  max(notesid)
from table
group by applicantid
```